I am currently using Cent OS Stream 9, when ever I run eg "sudo dnf install httpd", it updates all the old repost (already installed) first
The command sudo dnf install httpd is updating all the previously installed repositories.


Please, don't post images of text

what's the problem? you don't describe a problem.

The screenshot just shows dnf querying the enabled repositories to check for packages; it is not "updating" anything on them.
Note that it also says that httpd is already installed, so there's nothing to do.
Whenever you install a package, the system might install new packages or update already installed packages, due to dependencies.
